# Something strange going on with plank

Tags: plank

So I have a few apps docked on my plank, but I notice some apps not showing up on plank anymore when I have it opened. For example, if I load scratch-text-editor from the slingshot launcher, it will load up but the icon does not show up in plank. The only way I can see scratch-text-editor in plank is if I alt+tab and switched through the opened apps OR if I pinned scratch before opening it. I think the issue is that it only shows pinned apps on plank so opening any new app that was not pinned will not show up, very odd. I tried reinstalling plank and that didn't fix the issue either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `plank --preferences` and select "Show Unpinned" on Behaviour-tab.
[image]