# Certain application icons does not show up in dock when opened

Tags: applications, plank, icons

When I open qBittorrent or calibre they show for a moment in the dock and then go away. I am using **qBittorrent v3.3.1** which is in the official repository and **calibre v2.70** which I downloaded from calibre website.

I searched around and found two questions relevant to my problem. [This question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/something-strange-going-on-with-plank) is similar but the solution does not work for me. I already had the **Show Unpinned** option ticked.

[This question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/one-of-my-apps-has-a-second-fuzzy-icon-in-plank-how-can-i-workaround-this)  deals with multiple icons of same application.

I found a workaround for qBittorrent. There is a qBittorrent icon at the top when it is running. Clicking on this icon brings up a menu with a option **Hide**. Clicking **Hide** twice in this menu brings back qBittorrent icon in plank.

**UPDATE:**

The list of softwares seems to be growing. Now mousepad and virtualbox also do not show up in the dock.

Comment: Does this happen if you try to run these applications from a guest account as well?

Comment: I tested with various softwares. Only Codeblocks and Texmaker seems to  have this problem in guest account.

Comment: There has been a plank update yesterday (to 0.11.3), in my installation this bug does not happen any more. Can you check it for yours?

Comment: No that does not solve the problem in my computer.

Comment: same issue here, did anyone solve this issue?

Comment: this is a bug. has it been reported? I have noticed this in version 0.11.4.8-a996

Answer (score 3):

Same issue. Currently I go to dock preference (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + Right Click), comportment, and I disable/enable Show unpinned.
But it's not a solution of course.

It's boring but it's work (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Comment: no problem. it's not realy an answer but just for wait a fix or something better.

Answer (score 1):

For Calibre go to preferences/ look and feel and enable tray icon. 
That makes it stay in plank too.

I haven't tried this for other apps.

Comment: This is a possible workaround, a real solution would be nicer to have...

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution to me currently is to make plank strict between workspace and switch the workspace ,on ubuntu, or linux mint: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+(<kbd>←</kbd>or<kbd>→</kbd>). it refreshes the plank.

Answer (score -2):

@Ibraheem Moosa The solution is quite simple.
The only thing you have to do is edit the file `/usr/share/applications/calibre-gui.desktop` with root rights and change the line:

> `Exec=calibre --detach %F`

To

> `Exec=calibre`

Comment: It doesn't work.